# Use tkinter checkbutton values after window closes

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter. I'm trying to build a popup form initiated from a script that will offer several checkboxes to set variables I need in the script once the window is closed. I'm fine when the frame is open, but I can't find a way to pass the variables out for later use. In the code below, I'd like to add another button that will set those variables for varPDF and varSHP (global?) and close the window.

```
from tkinter import *

class mainwindow():
    def __init__(self, master):

        def setValues(var, entry):
            if varPDF.get() == True:
                print('varPDF is 1')
            else:
                print('varPDF is 0')
            if varSHP.get() == True:
                print('varPDF is 1')
            else:
                print('varSHP is 0')

            print('PDF:', varPDF.get(), ';', 'SHP: ', varSHP.get())

        self.master = master
        window = (self.master)

        varPDF = BooleanVar()
        checkbutton = Checkbutton(window, text="PDF", variable=varPDF)
        checkbutton.grid(column=0, row=0)

        varSHP = BooleanVar()
        checkbutton = Checkbutton(window, text="SHP", variable=varSHP)
        checkbutton.grid(column=0, row=1)

        button1 = Button(window,text=u"Quit", command=self.end)
        button1.grid(column=2, row=3)

        button2 = Button(window,text=u"Show", command=lambda: setValues(varPDF, varSHP))
        button2.grid(column=1, row=3)

    def end(self):
        self.master.destroy()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    window = mainwindow(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What are you expecting by setting variables after window closes? It is usless.

Comment: I don't see how I'm setting variables after the window closes. I believe I'm correctly setting the variables while the window is open as is demonstrated by the "Show" button. What I'm looking for is how to have those variables available after the window closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get to a solution using global variables and setting up functions that set them when a checkbutton was clicked. It may not be the most elegant solution, but it works.

```
##############################################################
# SET GLOBAL VARS
global sVar
sVar = 'STOPIT'
global globPDF
globPDF = 0
global globSHP
globSHP = 0

##############################################################
# INPUT DIALOG
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class mainwindow():
    def __init__(self, master):

        def set_globPDF_to_one():
            global globPDF
            globPDF = 1
        def set_globPDF_to_zero():
            global globPDF
            globPDF = 0     

        def set_globSHP_to_one():
            global globSHP
            globSHP = 1
        def set_globSHP_to_zero():
            global globSHP
            globSHP = 0

        def setValues():
            if varPDF.get() == True:
                set_globPDF_to_one()
            else:
                set_globPDF_to_zero()

            if varSHP.get() == True:
                set_globSHP_to_one()
            else:
                set_globSHP_to_zero()

        self.master = master
        window = (self.master)

        ttk.Label(window, text="Select Output:").grid(column=1
                 , row=1, sticky=W)

        varPDF = BooleanVar()
        cbxPDF = Checkbutton(window, text="PDF",
                             variable=varPDF, command=lambda: setValues())
        cbxPDF.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)

        varSHP = BooleanVar()
        cbxSHP = Checkbutton(window, text="SHP",
                             variable=varSHP, command=lambda: setValues())
        cbxSHP.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=W)

        btnQuit = Button(window,text=u"Quit", command=self.end)
        btnQuit.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=E, pady=4, padx=10)

        btnSbmt = Button(window,text=u"Submit", command=self.submit)
        btnSbmt.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=W, pady=4, padx=10)

    def submit(self):
        def set_sVar_to_run():
            global sVar
            sVar = 'COPYIT'

        set_sVar_to_run()
        self.master.destroy()

    def end(self):
        def set_sVar_to_stop():
            global sVar
            sVar = 'STOPIT'

        set_sVar_to_stop()
        print()
        print('Quit')
        self.master.destroy()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    window = mainwindow(root)
    root.lift()
    root.attributes('-topmost',True)
    root.after_idle(root.attributes,'-topmost',True)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# show output variables
print('sVar: '+sVar)
print('globPDF: '+str(globPDF))
print('globSHP: '+str(globSHP))
```